# Aiogram sqlite3 Не записывает id

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Постоянная регистрация   if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)): db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
Указал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или текст ошибок картинками, это противоречит местным традициям.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ID заполнялся, нужно в параметре столбца выставить фильтр "Primary Key" (первичный ключ)